# Symfony 2 Bundle Responsibilities and Structure

Tags: php, symfony

I am confused at when to create a new bundle or when just to create a new controller and CRUD in Symfony 2. If I have an entity that has joining tables to other entities should that all be in the same bundle.

An example would be I have a user bundle and I wanted users to be able to like videos in the system. There for the user and a video will be linked in a joining table.

Before I started the project I would have said that I would need to create a video bundle and a user bundle, but if they both need to reference each other should they be in the same bundle?

And if the answer is that they should be in separate bundles what is the best practice to reference them in either of their views and controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go for packing common features in the same bundle. It's quite hard to understand when you start learning Symfony 2, I know. Consider, for example, [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle): it defines common and reusable code for CRUD operations on users, groups, authentication and so on.

As a starting point you should learn [How to Define Relationships with Abstract Classes and Interfaces](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) and [Doctrine Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) (mapped superclasses are very useful for extending your bundle, with some limitations).

Comment: I was afraid the answer would be above my current understanding of OOP principles, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.